# Magento Setup AngularJS Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, magento, docker

I just setup the newest Magento 2.1.9 in a Docker environment and wanted to start the setup but the setup-interface never loads.

I get a few JS / Angular related errors in the console:
[image: AngularJS Errors in the Console / Screenshot]

The Javascript files on the page all load normally so I don't see a server error here but maybe I'm missing something.

I can't find anything related to that problem on the support forums etc.

Network Tab:
[image: Network Tab]

Comment: Can you check in Chrome Dev Tools Network tab and see if something is wrong there?

Comment: I added the Screenshots now.